# Remote debugging ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging, attach-to-process

I have an `ASP.NET` application (.NET 4.0) on `Windows 2008 Server` (IIS 7.0). I've installed a `Microsoft web express` but it doesn't support `attach to process` feature; also I don't want to transfer source code to the server.

Is there any way to remotely attach `w3wp.exe` and debug `.NET` local code (I have `RDP` administrator access on server) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anything other than Visual Studio Professional has "Attach to Process" which works over a network.

If/when you do get hold of VS Professional, you should read about [msvsmon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) - the remote debugging feature of Visual Studio. msvsmon is a little bit of software that sits on the server and enabled a remote debugging scenario.

Comment: I used it. The problem is remote server is on internet and I cannot use it's static IP address as `Qualifier` in `Attach Process` window.

Comment: Hang on - I've just answered almost a duplicate of this question from you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753645/remote-debugging-asp-net-applications-on-a-server-with-static-ip-address/4753940#4753940

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a solution, but IIS Express is a free version of IIS 7.5 that is optimized for developer scenarios.  This might be something which would work well for you instead of Microsoft Web Express.  It was just released.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx

Edit:  Just re-read your question and understand this may be a limitation of your IDE.   This post notes that IIS 7.5 express will work with Visual Web Developer (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)

Comment: My server is a production server and I cannot use `IIS Express edition` on it.