# Remote debugging ASP.NET applications on a server with static IP address

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, static-ip-address

All of examples on web assume the remote server which we are going to debug remotely is on the same network. I have only a static IP address and using `RDP` I connect to server.

I've installed `Remote Debugger` on remote machine but cannot set the static IP address as `Qualifier` in visual studio -> debug -> attach to process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username@machinename construct displayed in msvsmon is the text that needs to go into the Qualifier box in Visual Studio -> Attach to Process.

For example, where msvsmon says:

```
msvsmon started a new server named 'tf@macmini'. Waiting for new connections.
```

you would type tf@macmini into the qualifier box.

For a machine out on the internet, I'd guess you use username@[ip address here], e.g.

```
tf@123.234.32.1
```

Though you will need to make sure, at a minimum, firewalls and authentication are set up correctly. (The debugging will not occur via RDP.) There's an article on the firewall side of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126350.aspx). Can't remember off the top what the authentication involves, although I suspect as a minimum you will need an account on both machines with the same username and password.

Comment: I've tried `user@x.x.x.x` but visual studio says: `Login Failure: unknown username or bad password`. I'm sure the username is correct and I didn't provide the password as your example.

Comment: Have you made sure BOTH the username and the password on both machines are the same? That should be enough. There are other ways to accomplish this though - see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f.aspx